# How Many Shader Programs Do I Really Need?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

Let's say I have a shader set up to use 3 textures, and that I need to render some polygon that needs all the same shader attributes except that it requires only 1 texture. I have noticed on my own graphics  card that I can simply call glDisableVertexAttrib() to disable the other two textures, and that doing so apparently causes the disabled texture data received by the fragment shader to be all white (1.0f). In other words, if I have a fragment shader instruction (pseudo-code)...

```
final_red = tex0.red * tex1.red * tex2.red
```

...the operation produces the desired final value regardless whether I have 1, 2, or 3 textures enabled. From this comes a number of questions:

1. Is it legit to disable expected textures like this, or is it a coincidence that my particular graphics card has this apparent mathematical safeguard?
2. Is the "best practice" to create a separate shader program that only expects a single texture for single texture rendering?
3. If either approach is valid, is there a benefit to creating a second shader program? I'm thinking it would be cost less time to make 2 glDisableVertexAttrib() calls than to make a glUseProgram() + 5-6 glGetUniform() calls, but maybe #4 addresses that issue.
4. When changing the active shader program with glUseProgram() do I need to call glGetUniform... functions every time to re-establish the location of each uniform in the program, or is the location of each expected to be consistent until the shader program is deallocated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling vertex attributes would not really disable your textures, it would just give you undefined texture coordinates. That ***might*** produce an affect similar to disabling a certain texture, but to do this properly you should use a uniform or possibly subroutines (if you have dozens of variations of the same shader).

As far as time taken to disable a vertex array state, that's probably going to be slower than changing a uniform value. Setting uniform values don't really affect the render pipeline state, they're just small changes to memory. Likewise, constantly swapping the current GLSL program does things like invalidate shader cache, so that's also significantly more expensive than setting a uniform value.

If you're on a modern GL implementation (GL 4.1+ or one that implements `GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects`) you can even set uniform values without binding a GLSL program at all, simply by calling `glProgramUniform* (...)`

I am most concerned with the fact that you think you need to call `glGetUniformLocation (...)` each time you set a uniform's value. The only time the location of a uniform in a GLSL program changes is when you link it. Assuming you don't constantly re-link your GLSL program, you only need to query those locations once and store them persistently.

Comment: The only concern I would have about using a uniform and/or subroutine to control what textures are considered during shader calculations is that somewhere I read when you use "if" statements the GPU most likely processes ALL branches and then makes a decision as to which one to use. That seems like a pretty big performance hit as well.

Comment: GPUs haven't worked that way in years. They do, however, schedule blocks of fragment shaders into thread scheduling units called warps/wavefronts. So you might have 64 fragments scheduled into one warp... if all of the 64 fragments follow the same control path (e.g. same `if` condition) then there's no penalty, but if some of them take one branch and the rest take another then all of the fragment shaders have to wait for the longest one to finish. It's called divergent control flow, but it sounds like your entire pass would use the same branch condition making it largely irrelevant.